# In C++ is the expression for a value to access a static member sequenced before the static member access?

Tags: c++, standards, expression-evaluation

Suppose I have:

```
struct Foo {
    static void bar();
};

Foo foo() { return Foo(); }
```

In the expression `foo().bar()` is the call to `foo` **guaranteed** to happen BEFORE the call to `bar()`? Where is this stated in the standard?

The doubt is because the *value* of the result of the call is not used, and the type is known at compile time...

Comment: ["Class member access"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.ref#1) and [footnote](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.ref#footnote-59).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[expr.ref] p1](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#1) states:

> The postfix expression before the dot or arrow is evaluated; the result of that evaluation, together with the *id-expression*, determines the result of the entire postfix expression.

This means that for `E1.E2`, `E1` takes place before `E1.E2`, but there is no sequencing of `E1` and `E2`<sup>(1)</sup>.
You have a function call of the pattern `foo().bar()`. The function call to `bar` is sequenced after `foo().bar` as a whole.

Therefore yes, the call to `foo()` happens before the call to `bar()`.

Interestingly, the wording does not use the term "sequenced", which is unusual and likely an editorial issue.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> <sub>`E2` is an *[id-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.general#nt:id-expression)* (e.g. `foo`) which is either a *qualified-id* or *unqualified-id*, and such an expression in itself performs no value computation and has no side effects. There is nothing to be sequenced anyway.</sub>

Comment: `E2` (`bar`) isn't an expression, so it can't have any sequencing.

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#11